# For SQL query, count with where clause error

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql database I have a table like this:

```
create table review(
reviewId varchar(12) primary key,
helpfulness double,
reviewRating integer)
```

I try to count helpful and unhelpful `group by` `reviewRating` and `helpfulness` `where` >=0.75 as unhelpfulness or where < 0.75 as helpfulness. How could I get the result like this?

```html
unhelpfulness helpfulness reviewRating
5             2           1
4             2           2 
3             4           3
```

I trying to do like this, but it seems like count did not work and join is invalid at that position.

```sql
SELECT a.count AS HELPFUL, b.count AS UNHELPFUL 
FROM review a where helpfulness>=0.75 group by a.reviewRating
OUTER JOIN review b where helpfulness<0.75 group by b.reviewRating
on a.reviewRating = b.reviewRating
```

Comment: Question: won't any helpfulness value greater than 0.75 be counted? In other words, any integer from 1 - 5?

Answer (score 3):

In Mysql you can do so by using `sum` with some condition or expression it will result as a boolean (0/1) and this way you can get the conditional count

```
SELECT a.reviewRating,
SUM(helpfulness>=0.75) AS HELPFUL,
SUM(helpfulness < 0.75)AS UNHELPFUL 
FROM review a 
GROUP BY a.reviewRating
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement conditional aggregation with `case` expression:

```
select a.reviewRating
     ,  count(case when helpfulness >= 0.75 then helpfulness end) as helpful
     ,  count(case when helpfulness < 0.75 then helpfulness end) as unhelpful 
from review a 
group by a.reviewRating
```